# Materials have gone weird after doing a "cell fracture" on my object

Tags: cell-fracture

[image: The weird blue/green pattered lines are my problem]Hi everyone, I am sorry if this question has been asked somewhere else (I have looked at multiple forums to find an answer, but no luck yet).

I have a building that I added "Cell fracture" to. However, when I do, some of the cells have weird material changes. I have attached an image to explain this better.

My material is just a simple .png file.

[Here is the link to the model that I have used.](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/popeninnc7781/Large+Building+01)

[image]

Any help?
Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  Some more info might be helpful, such as some details on the material (procedural, texture on a UV map, combo?), maybe a screenshot including the Shader Editor.  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  Not sure about this time, but just so you know, the Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have edited my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to mainly be the model's UV mapping, although the trigon topology might also cause Cell Fracture some trouble:

[image]

The texture map is 256 pixels wide by 1 pixel tall, with the UV islands tiny spots.  When Cell Fracture makes new objects from a UV mapped source it makes a new UV map for each of them, and it's having trouble with this:

[image]

I'd recommended retopologizing and reworking the UV map of the building before using Cell Fracture on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am fairly new to blender, so I am not too sure what you mean by "retopologizing and reworking the UV map". Could you explain a bit further?
Thanks.

Comment: The topology and UV mapping of the model is common (and appropriate) for many games, but Blender's having trouble reading the tight coordinates of the UV map.  Googling on "UV Mapping" "Blender" should get you started, for more depth the Blender Manual is helpful:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/applying_image.html .  Once you have that fixed, if Cell Fracture gives you good results you shouldn't need to retopologize (change the structure of the mesh).  There's a 600 character limit on comments here, how much more detail do you need?

Comment: That should be good. I will try this when I get home and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hope it helps!  If you need more info on UV unwrapping or retopologizing then searching this site, youtube, and/or forums like BlenderArtists should prove useful.  In the meantime, if I've answered your original question I'd appreciate it if you'd click the checkmark next to my answer.